# Building a calendar from a Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, calendar

Does anyone know a calendar app that can read a Word document and build a calendar based on each line?

Example:

```
Monday 
 1. 8-9 Wake up
 2. 9-12 Work out
 3. 12-6 Work
```

Using that it should build a plain text calendar that should looks something like this:

[image]

Does anyone know anything like that?

Comment: So I would just like it to look something more like http://goo.gl/EQLff than just plain text. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry it shouldn't have been tagged outlook that is a mistake. This had nothing to do with outlook. This is what I'm looking for 
plain text with times like in the example go into a calendar app and builds it for you.

Comment: I included the image in your post, thanks for clearing it up. So why are those Word documents there? Why do they need to be a plain text calendar? If you explained more about the circumstances, it'd be easier to find possible workarounds for your *real* problem rather than fixing your attempted solution.

Comment: Thank for your help and understanding. An old co worker has a massive word document that has it in plain text and it is simply not easy to consume but if it were something like a calendar it would be much easier to understand and see.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're handy with styles, etc in Word and just re-laying it out in Word isn't working for you.

I don't understand if you are looking to:

1. Do a 1-time conversion or keep the document as-is;
2. Insert these lines as entries in a calendar program or just display the data in a calendar-y format.

If you are doing a 1-time conversion then just save the document in plain-text format and work with the lines.

If you want to import the lines into a calendar program, you can export them to .ics files, which can be imported into pretty much any calendaring program like Google Calendar, etc. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar for details on the layout.

If you're just looking for a display, tag the lines with date/activity style names using syntax like

```
<style type="text/css">
 ol.daylist { list-style-type: lower-roman }
 li.dayofweek { list-style-type: none }
 li.todoitem { background-color:#00ff00;}
</style>
<ol class="daylist">
    <li class="dayofweek">Monday</ol>
    <li class="todoitem">8-9 Wake up</li>
    <li class="todoitem">9-12 Work out</li>
</ol>
```

and use a CSS file to display the data how you like.

If you want to use the existing document as-is and just have the display appear dynamically, use VBA to read the contents of the document and write out the lines as a html file which you could then open with the system web browser.

This sample code adapted from http://www.exceltip.com/show_tip/Applications_-_Word,_Outlook_in_VBA/Control_Word_from_Excel_using_VBA_in_Microsoft_Excel/465.html shows how you can use a VBA macro to open the document and read each line.

You can see where, if the document uses styles, you could test for the style and use that to determine which style to assign to the line as you write it to an html file.

```
Sub OpenAndReadWordDoc()
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim tString As String, tRange As Word.Range
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("c:\calendar.docm")
With wrdDoc
    For p = 1 To .Paragraphs.Count
        Set tRange = .Range(Start:=.Paragraphs(p).Range.Start, End:=.Paragraphs(p).Range.End)
            tString = tRange.Text
            tString = Left(tString, Len(tString) - 1) 'this is to avoid including CR/LF
           MsgBox (tString)
        Next p
        .Close ' close the document
    End With
    wrdApp.Quit ' close the Word application
    Set wrdDoc = Nothing
    Set wrdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Updated the answer based on the no-Outlook change. Also tried to format code more appropriately this time.

Comment: [nice link to word macro commands for my own reference](http://www.thezcorp.com/VBACodeSamples.aspx)